# ion-refresher has stopped appearing after upgrade

Tags: ionic-framework

I recently upgraded Ionic from 1.1.0 to 1.3.1 and now my ion-refresher has stopped working. Nothing appears when I drag down on the page and the event does not fire.
In my development environment I have:

```
<ion-view view-title="Test">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-refresher pulling-text="Pull to refresh..."
                       on-refresh="vm.refresh()">
        </ion-refresher>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item>Item 1</ion-item>
            <ion-item>Item 2</ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Did you check on [github's issues](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues), or Ionic's forum, or on slack, you will more likely get a quicker response on slack's forum for ionic.

Comment: Does the method fire?

Comment: Could you please try to make a Fiddle about this or something. Your code seems fine so it must be something else in your app. You might even catch it while doing an example for us ;)

Comment: @thepio the CodePen linked to Ionic's own blog doesn't work. Will that do? Question edited to add links

Comment: @Colin actually that codePen link you provided works for me. It doesn't work for you? I'm talking about this link: http://codepen.io/andrewmcgivery/pen/ZYyVgp

Comment: @thepio ok it is working. I was pulling on the text "Pull To Refresh", and it only works if you pull on the body below the header. I've removed the links I just added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the versions of Ionic, I discovered that the problem was introduced between 1.1.1 and 1.2.1
Then I compared the html being produced by each version and noticed that the earlier version included `class="js-scrolling"` on the refresher. I also examined the [release notes for 1.2.1](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/releases/tag/v1.2.1). And there I found another clue, buried in some [comments on issue #4758](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4758):

> "By default, Ionic 1.2 will use native scrolling on all platforms."
>   ion-refresher is based on jsScrolling. If you want ion-refresher you
>   should enable jsScrolling. You can do it by adding 
>   `$ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(true);` in your app config

So I added a script file to my `index.html` containing this code:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module('app')
        .config(ionicConfig);

    ionicConfig.$inject = ['$ionicConfigProvider'];

    function ionicConfig($ionicConfigProvider) {
        $ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(true);
    }

})();
```

And now my refresher is working again.

**EDIT**
At least it was working - in the Ripple emulator. But when I tried to run on a device (deploying from Visual Studio 2015) the app would not deploy or run until I removed that line. So now I have this code:

```
function ionicConfig($ionicConfigProvider) {
    //detecting Ripple emulator
    var emulating = window.parent && window.parent.ripple;
    if (emulating) {
        $ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(true);
    }
}
```